# Can an algebraic variety be embedded in projective space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, schemes, projective-space, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over field $k$ .
$X$ can be embedded in a complete variety by Nagata's compactification theorem.

Moreover, can we embed $X$ in a projective space $\mathbb{P}_k^n$  $???$
Please give me references which contain either proof or counter examples.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka%27s_example shows that arbitrary varieties over fields cannot necessarily be embedded in projective space.

Answer (score 2):

From KReiser's comment:

Hironaka's example ([link at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hironaka%27s_example)) shows that arbitrary varieties over fields cannot necessarily be embedded in projective space.